# Run Perl Script on Several files Simultaneously

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have written a Perl script that reads in a data file, line by line, does some computations and returns 3 files as outputs; I have also written it so that it reads through every *.csv file that I have in my directory, one file at the time, returning the 3 separate output files for each input file (so for 10 csv input files, when my script is done, I have 30 output files.)

However, when I run my script, I see that it only runs on one core. What I would like to do is make my script run simultaneously on several input files: is this even possible? Or, alternatively, what would be a better option? I'm working on a Windows machine.

Comment: [Use Parallel::ForkManager](http://www.nu42.com/2012/04/can-parallelforkmanager-speed-up.html): On Windows, the "forks" will be Windows threads anyway. Also, post what you have tried so far if you want specific help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two (main) options for using more processors in Perl.

Threads and forks. There's a certain amount of similarity between them, but some crucial differences. `fork()` is a native system call on Unix, and it's extremely efficient (it's used a lot). On Windows you don't have it - perl emulates it's functionality quite well though.

`fork` clones your program exactly - it makes a 'parent' and 'child' and the *only* difference is the return code from fork. Codes resumes from exactly the same point, so you *can* end up with some slightly strange behaviour.

Note for example when you run:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pid = fork();

if ( $pid ) { 
   print "$$ is the parent - child is $pid\n";
}
else {
   print "$$ is the child\n";
}
```

You should be aware - every variable that exists before is still defined in each 'fork' but it's a separate copy. This leads you to the next challenge, which is inter-process communications. This is a sufficiently big topic that it's got it's own perl documentation page [`perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html)

When it comes to more paralleism though, fork can somewhat awkward because it's a low level call. How many lines do you think this prints?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @fruits = qw ( apple pear lemon lime cucumber ); 

foreach my $fruit ( @fruits ) {
    my $pid = fork();
    if ( $pid ) { 
        print "Parent $$ with a child of $pid has a fruit of $fruit\n";
    } 
    else {
       print "Child of $$ has a fruit of $fruit\n";
    }
}
```

Because the fork is nested, it happens more times than you might intuitively guess. It's also somewhat easy to `fork` too much with a loop, and you can create a denial of service condition.

Fortunately, there is a solution - `Parallel::Forkmanager` implements some simple mechanisms for controlling forks, which makes it a lot smoother.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Parallel::ForkManager; 

my @fruits = qw ( apple pear lemon lime cucumber ); 
my $manager = Parallel::ForkManager -> new ( 5 ); 

print "Parent: $$\n";
foreach my $fruit ( @fruits ) {
    $manager -> start and next;
    print "Child of $$ - $fruit\n";
    $manager -> finish; 
}

$manager -> wait_all_children;
```

For the sake of completeness - I'll also mention [`threads`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html). They're another way of doing things, but they're slightly counter-intuitively not lightweight as they are in other languages. They're also a status of 'discouraged':

> The "interpreter-based threads" provided by Perl are not the fast, lightweight system for multitasking that one might expect or hope for. Threads are implemented in a way that make them easy to misuse. Few people know how to use them correctly or will be able to provide help.
>   The use of interpreter-based threads in perl is officially discouraged.

So where forks are fairly easy to have lots and lots of, threads are basically best thought of as separate processes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub thread_sub {
   print threads -> self -> tid(). ": @_\n";
}

my @fruits = qw ( apple pear lemon lime cucumber ); 

foreach my $fruit ( @fruits ) {
    threads -> create ( \&thread_sub, $fruit );
}

foreach my $thr ( threads -> list ) {
    $thr -> join;
}
```

In either case though, you should be aware - parallel processing means your code no longer happens in an obvious sequential fashion. This means you'll have some really fruity and funky bugs that will be horrific to debug if you're not careful. So make sure you code works sequentially first before even trying to go near parallelism.

You should also be aware - you only get linear performance improvements for as long as your limiting factor is purely CPU. It generally isn't. Disk IO is invariably much slower. You mention processing several files. If the emphasis is on processing, rather than reading data - then parallelism will help.

But disks are pretty slow, and 'thrashing' them by trying to stream data from multiple locations will slow them down more. So you don't gain much - if anything - by parallising IO intensive tasks (disk traversals, bulk file reads etc.), and you can quite easily make matters worse.